# How many ways can a tennis team of $4$ players be selected from a group of $6$ boys and $5$ girls without restriction?

Tags: combinatorics

A tennis team consists of $4$ players who must be chosen from a group of $6$ boys and $5$ girls. Find the number of ways the team can be picked:   without restriction.

I worked it out manually, is there a simple formula for this

Comment: $\binom{6+5}{4}=\binom{11}{4}=\frac{11!}{4!\cdot(11-4)!}=\frac{11!}{4!\cdot7!}=330$.

Comment: do you mean the number of different teams of named players?  Or do you mean the number of Boy/Girl combinations - e.g. 4 girls, 2 boys 2 girls etc - I suppose the second one is a bit obvious though - the first one above must have taken some counting

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{6+5}{4} = \frac{11!}{4!(11-4)!} = 330$

Answer (score 0):

We have $11$ choices for the first player, $10$ choices for the second player, $9$ choices for the third player, and $8$ choices for the fourth player.  By the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), the number of ways of selecting the players *in order* is 
$$11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 7920$$
This would be the answer if we were assigning the selected players to play first singles, second singles, third singles, and fourth singles.  However, if we are just picking a team without regard to position, selecting Anne, Barbara, Clive, and David yields the same team as selecting David, Barbara, Anne, and Clive (assuming we have not picked two different players with the same name).  The number of orders in which we could pick the same four players is 
$$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$
Hence, the number of teams we could select without regard to position on the team is 
$$\frac{11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 330$$
where we divide the total number of ordered selections by the number of different orders in which we could choose the same four players.

The number $n!$, read "[n factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)", is defined to be $1$ if $n = 0$ and to be the product of the first $n$ positive integers if $n$ is a positive integer.  Hence, 
$$4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$
If we multiply the numerator and denominator of the quotient
$$\frac{11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$
by $7!$, we obtain
$$\frac{11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7!}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 7!} = \frac{11!}{4!7!} = 330$$
The expression 
$$C(n, k) = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of $k$ elements selected from $n$ elements without regard to the order of selection, that is, the number of $k$-element subsets that can be selected from a set with $n$ elements.

If we multiply and divide the expression $11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ by $7!$, we obtain
$$\frac{11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7!}{7!} = \frac{11!}{7!}$$
The expression
$$P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
is the number of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), that is, the number of ordered selections of $k$ elements selected from a set with $n$ elements.

Since no positions on the team have been specified, the answer to your question is 
$$\binom{11}{4} = \frac{11!}{4!7!} = 330$$